React Context is not changing
I have created a context and I want to change it when I click in SingleProduct component button but it doesn't work
I have ctreated my context in a .ts file DataModalContext.ts:
import { createContext } from "react";

export const DataModalContext = createContext(true)

SingleProduct component:
import { Skeleton } from '@mui/material'
import { DataModalContext } from './../../../../context/DataModalContext';
import { useState } from 'react';

interface ISingleProduct {
  imageSource?: string;
  imageText?: string;
  text?: string;
  SingleProductModalActivator?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}

const SingleProduct: React.FC<ISingleProduct> = ({ imageSource, imageText, text, SingleProductModalActivator }): JSX.Element => {

  const [SingleClick, setSingleClick] = useState(false)

  const clickHandler = () => {
    SingleProductModalActivator!(true)
    setSingleClick(!SingleClick)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <DataModalContext.Provider value={SingleClick}>
        <div className='relative h-[330px] w-[230px] rounded-md shadow-lg p-[15px]'>
          <div className={"relative product-image w-[200px] h-[230px]"}>
            <div className='w-[200px] h-[200px] overflow-hidden rounded-md'>
              {
                imageSource ? (<img src={imageSource} alt={imageText} />) : (<Skeleton variant='rectangular' width={200} height={200} className='rounded-md' />)
              }
            </div>
            <div className='bg-gray-300 absolute bottom-[10px] left-0 right-0 py-[1px] rounded-full'></div>
          </div>
          <div className={"product-text "}>
            {
              text ? (<p>{text}</p>) : (<Skeleton variant='text' width={100} />)
            }
          </div>
          <div onClick={() => clickHandler()} className='absolute bottom-2 right-2 text-xs cursor-pointer select-none px-2 py-1 bg-cyan-700 text-white rounded-md'>
            more info
          </div>
        </div>
      </DataModalContext.Provider>

    </>
  )
}

export default SingleProduct

and I want to see the changes of my context in modalProduct Component:
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

import "./style.css"
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { DataModalContext } from '../../../../context/DataModalContext';


interface IModalProduct {
    activate?: boolean;
    activator?: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const ModalProduct: React.FC<IModalProduct> = ({activate, activator}):JSX.Element => {
  const DataModalProduct = useContext(DataModalContext)
  const handleClick = () => {
    activator!(!activate)
  }
  return (
    <div className={`ModalProduct fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 ${activate ? "z-40 opacity-[100%]" : "z-[-10] opacity-0"} z-40`}>
        <div className={"bg-white h-[80vh] w-[80vw] absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] rounded-md shadow-lg"}>
          <p>
            {
              DataModalProduct ? "clicked" : "Single Product clicked"
            }
          </p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => handleClick()} className='absolute top-5 left-5 cursor-pointer bg-white h-[40px] w-[40px] rounded-full shadow-md'>
          <CloseIcon className={'absolute top-[50%] left-[50%] translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%]'} />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ModalProduct

but it doesn't work.
I have created another context like this and it is working properly.

ModalProduct needs to be a child of the DataModalContext.Provider to be able to access the context value.

Where are you using the ModalProduct in your application? The DataModalContext.Provider should ideally wrap your entire application so that the component tree can have access to it
